# Pythonのシンボル「&」と「>>」とはどういう意味ですか?

Tags: python

Pythonで`&`と`>>`はどのような意味でしょうか。
うまくWeb検索できないのでご教示ください。

`&`が積(intersection)を求める[集合演算子](https://qiita.com/Tocyuki/items/0bc783daab382ef7a0ec#%E7%A9%8Dintersection)であることは分かっています。
しかし以下のコードには当てはまらないように見えます：

```
def numberOfSteps (self, num: int) -> int:
    stepCount = 0 if num else 1
    while num:
        stepCount += (num & 1) + 1
        num >>= 1
    return stepCount - 1
```

---

<sup>この質問は[¿Qué significan los símbolos "&" y ">>" en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/453092)を和訳したものです。</sup>

Comment: Q&Aを翻訳していただきありがとうございます。ちょっとだけ日本語のnative speakerには読みにくいmachine translationのような表現を書き換えました。また、Pythonの初心者にも分かりやすいように説明やリンクを追加しました。

Comment: Hai,  arigatō

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## ビット演算子

ビット演算子は、数値をビット(0と1)で計算する[ビット演算](https://qiita.com/7shi/items/41d262ca11ea16d85abc)と呼ばれる処理に使用されます。

## オペレーター `>>` (bitwise right shift)

`>>`演算子は **右シフト** または **right shift(rshift)** と呼ばれ、n ビットの右シフトを示します。
例：

```
a = 60            #0011 1100 
b = 13            #0000 1101 

#もし >> 2 を実行した場合は2ビット分(2進数で2桁分)右に動きます
r = a >> 2
#r = 0000 1111
print(r) #15
```

右シフトと`num/pow(2,n)`が同一の処理に見えますが、それは間違いです。
右シフトの結果は整数を返しますが、除算は小数を返すことがあります。
例：

```
#operator
60 >> 2
#15

#formula
60/pow(2,2)
#15

#again
60 >> 3
#7

60/pow(2,3)
#7.5
```

後者(#again)の場合は、ビット演算と除算で異なる結果になります。
整数で除算するには`int(60/pow(2,3))`のようにintへキャストする方法があります。
また、`60//pow(2,3)`のように商の整数部分を返す切り捨て除算`//`を使用する方法もあります。

## オペレーター `&` (bitwise and)

最初に述べたようにビット演算はビット単位であるため、真偽値(True/False)で使用されるので and 演算子と同じ意味にはなりません。
また、`&`で実行される操作はデータ型によって異なりますが、この演算子の興味深い点は、呼び出す関数を `__and__` と `__rand__` として再定義できることです。

この場合、`&`演算子は[set（集合）型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)の操作と同様にふるまいますが、ビット演算と同じように数字が両方とも 1 ならば 1 を、それ以外の場合は 0 を返します。
例：

```
a = 60            #0011 1100 
b = 13            #0000 1101

r = a & b 
#calculamos la interseccion entre 0011 1100 y 0000 1101
#0011 1100
#0000 1101
#interseccion -> 0000 1100
print(r) #12
```

この結果、出力は10進数で 12 を表すビット(2進数) 0000 1100 になります。

## ご質問のコード

ご質問のコードでは、`stepCount = 0 if num else 1`の行で引数`num`が`True`か`False`かを判定します。
任意の数または空でない文字列である場合は `True` になります。0 または空文字(`""`)の場合は`False`となり、`True`の場合は 0 を、`False`の場合は 1 を割り当てます。(cf: [三項演算子](https://qiita.com/howmuch515/items/bf6d21f603d9736fb4a5))
その後、`num & 1`で1(ビット単位)との積を求め、続いて`while`ループに移動します。

```
# num = 7 と仮定します
# if num の結果は True なので stepCount = 0 が代入されます

while num:
    stepCount += (num & 1) + 1 # (7と1の積)に1を足した値を加算します
    # つまり 0 += (1) +1 = 2 となります
    num >>= 1 # 1ビット右シフトします
    # 今回は3が返ります (0d7 = 0b111 → 0b11 = 0d3) ※0dは10進数、0bは2進数を示す
    # このループは num == 0 になるまで繰り返します
return stepCount - 1 # 上記の合計値から1を引いた値を返します
```

`num`が `0000 0000` になるまで右シフトを繰り返し、累積された値を返します。